# PHP API return JSON and print itself into the DOM structure

Tags: php, json, api, dom

I am trying to retrieve a response from Bittrex's rest API, i get a result but for some reason it prints, echo or w/e itself into the dom structure as soon as i recieve it, even if i just call and hold it in a variable?

Class

```
class Bittrex
{
    private $m_baseUrl;
    private $m_apiVersion = 'v1.1';
    private $m_apiKey;
    private $m_apiSecret;
    public function __construct ($p_apiKey, $p_apiSecret)
    {
        $this->m_apiKey = $p_apiKey;
        $this->m_apiSecret = $p_apiSecret;
        $this->m_baseUrl = 'https://bittrex.com/api/'.$this->m_apiVersion;
    }
    private function Call($p_function, $p_parameters = array(), $p_usingApiKey = false)
    {
        $l_uri = $this->m_baseUrl.$p_function;
        if($p_usingApiKey)
        {
            $p_parameters['apikey'] = $this->m_apiKey;
            $p_parameters['nonce'] = time();
        }
        if (!empty($p_parameters))
        {
            $l_uri .= '?'.http_build_query($p_parameters);
        }
        $l_curl = curl_init($l_uri);
            curl_setopt($l_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.hash_hmac('sha512', $l_uri, $this->m_apiSecret)));
        $l_curlResult = curl_exec($l_curl);
        return json_decode($l_curlResult);
    }
    /*
        Used to get the open and available trading markets at Bittrex along with other meta data.
    */
    public function GetMarkets()
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getmarkets');
    }
    /*
        Used to get all supported currencies at Bittrex along with other meta data.
    */
    public function GetCurrencies()
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getcurrencies');
    }
    /*
        Used to get the current tick values for a market.
    */
    public function GetTicker($p_market)
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getticker', array('market' => $p_market));
    }
    /*
        Used to get the last 24 hour summary of all active exchanges.
    */
    public function GetMarketSummaries()
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getmarketsummaries');
    }
    /*
        Used to get the last 24 hour summary for specific active exchanges.
    */
    public function GetMarketSummary($p_market)
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getmarketsummary', array('market' => $p_market));
    }
    /*
        Used to get retrieve the orderbook for a given market.
    */
    public function GetOrderBook($p_market, $p_type)
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getorderbook', array('market' => $p_market, 'type' => $p_type));
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve the latest trades that have occured for a specific market.
    */
    public function GetMarketHistory($p_market)
    {
        return $this->Call('/public/getmarkethistory', array('market' => $p_market));
    }
    /*
        Used to place a buy order in a specific market.
        Make sure you have the proper permissions set on your API keys for this call to work.
    */
    public function BuyLimit($p_market, $p_quantity, $p_rate)
    {
        return $this->Call('/market/buylimit', array('market' => $p_market, 'quantity' => $p_quantity, 'rate' => $p_rate), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to place an sell order in a specific market.
        Make sure you have the proper permissions set on your API keys for this call to work.
    */
    public function SellLimit($p_market, $p_quantity, $p_rate)
    {
        return $this->Call('/market/selllimit', array('market' => $p_market, 'quantity' => $p_quantity, 'rate' => $p_rate), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to cancel a buy or sell order.
    */
    public function Cancel($p_uuid)
    {
        return $this->Call('/market/cancel', array('uuid' => $p_uuid), true);
    }
    /*
        Get all orders that you currently have opened.
        A specific market can be requested.
    */
    public function GetOpenOrders($p_market = null)
    {
        return $this->Call('/market/getopenorders', array('market' => $p_market), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve all balances from your account.
    */
    public function GetBalances()
    {
        return $this->Call('/account/getbalances', array(), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve the balance from your account for a specific currency.
    */
    public function GetBalance($p_currency)
    {
        return $this->Call('/account/getbalance', array('currency' => $p_currency), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve or generate an address for a specific currency.
        If one does not exist, the call will fail and return ADDRESS_GENERATING until one is available.
    */
    public function GetDepositAddress($p_currency)
    {
        return $this->Call('/account/getdepositaddress', array('currency' => $p_currency), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to withdraw funds from your account.
        note: please account for txfee.
    */
    public function Withdraw($p_currency, $p_quantity, $p_address, $p_paymentId = null)
    {
        $l_parameters = array(
            'currency' => $p_currency,
            'quantity' => $p_quantity,
            'address' => $p_address
        );
        if($p_paymentId)
        {
            $l_parameters['paymentid'] = $p_paymentId;
        }
        return $this->Call('/account/withdraw', $l_parameters, true);
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve a single order by uuid.
    */
    public function GetOrder($p_uuid)
    {
        return $this->Call('/account/getorder', array('uuid' => $p_uuid), true);
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve your order history.
    */
    public function GetOrderHistory($p_market = null)
    {
        $l_parameters = array();
        if($p_market)
        {
            $l_parameters['market'] = $p_market;
        }
        return $this->Call('/account/getorderhistory', $l_parameters, true);
    }
    /*
        Used to retrieve your withdrawal history.
    */
    public function GetWithdrawalHistory($p_currency = null)
    {
        $l_parameters = array();
        if($p_currency)
        {
            $l_parameters['currency'] = $p_currency;
        }
        return $this->Call('/account/getwithdrawalhistory', $l_parameters, true);
    }
    /*  
        Used to retrieve your deposit history.
    */
    public function GetDepositHistory($p_currency = null)
    {
        $l_parameters = array();
        if($p_currency)
        {
            $l_parameters['currency'] = $p_currency;
        }
        return $this->Call('/account/getdeposithistory', $l_parameters, true);
    }
}
```

PHP code

```
$public = "My public key";
$private = "My private key";

require_once 'classes/bittrex.php';
$request = new Bittrex($public, $private);

$markets = $request->GetMarkets();
```

This is how the dom look like after the PHP

[image]

I have tried this aswell but it keeps printing itself into the whole structure, i don't know if i miss remember something or simply just do not know what is going on

Tried

```
$public = "My public key";
$private = "My private key";

require_once 'classes/bittrex.php';
$request = new Bittrex($public, $private);

$markets = $request->GetMarkets();
$data = json_decode($markets, true);
```

Can someone tell me how i can tame this data and maybe just hold it in a variable and loop through the data?

Comment: Have you tried using `curl_setopt($l_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

Comment: Thats it! Thanks to all of you really, i seriously just grew 3 grey hairs xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($l_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
>
> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: Ofcourse, oohhhmaaa gawd. thanks alot champ!

Thats correct, i just knew it was a no brainer, i hope someone else find this answer when they have coded all night and just can't figure out why it wount return as a string :) !